# Logic App dynamic content give null or ""

Tags: json, azure, jira, azure-logic-apps

I want to create small automation between Jira and Azure. To do this, I execute HTTP trigger from Jira, which send all request properties to Azure Logic App. In "When a HTTP request is received" step in Logic App I can see  properly JSON schema with all data which I need. In next steps for example I want to add user to Azure AD group. And problem starts here.

For example, I want to Initialize variable and set it with value from JSON. I choose properties from dynamic menu, but after script execute always it is null value ( but in first step in "raw output" I see whole schema with data). I tried many things - parse, compose, many different conversion - always without any luck - null value or "".

Expected value - when I want to initialize variable using Properties from Dynamic Content I want to have value from input json.

[Output from Jira](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNkWR.png)

[Output with the same JSON send from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gilka.png)

Thanks for any help !

--
[Flow example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXXBf.png)

[Flow result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCOEW.png)

Comment: Could you post some code with what you did?

Comment: I added screenshoots, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

If you send the json with application/json content-type, you could just select the property with the dynamic content, however if not you have to parse it to json format with `Parse Json` action.

AS for the schema, you need use your json data to generate it with `Use sample payload to generate schema`. Paste the sample json payload.

[image]

Then you will be able to select property. However you could not implement it dynamic content, you have to write the expression. The format will be like this `body('Parse_JSON')['test1']` and if your json has array data, you need to point the index it will be like this `body('Parse_JSON')['test2'][0]['test3']`.

Below is my test, you could have a try.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I want to do this using this context menu. Jira will send JSON file, so I shouldn`t Parse it to JSON once again. Please look at screenshoots which I add

Comment: @Kivas, I test, it's not json file problem,it's `Content-Type` problem, if you send json with `text/plain` even you set the schema you still need to parse it with `Parse JSON` action and if you send with `application/json` it will shows like your postman result. You could test with postman with `text/plain`, you will get the first result.

Comment: Please look in the header - it is send in a application/json format
{
    "headers": {
        "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Host": "prod-999.westeurope.logic.azure.com",
        "User-Agent": "Atlassian HttpClient unknown / JIRA-1001.0.0-SNAPSHOT (100107) / JIRA-Service-Desk-3.3.0-OD / Default",
        "Content-Length": "23609",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    },

Comment: @Kivas, if it's already application/json format, could you use Expression to get the value like `triggerBody()['test1']`.

Comment: @George_Chen Yes, but in the expression I can enter the same formula that can be clicked on the Dynamic menu, so this is not the problem (I think so). I switched output from Jira to plain / text so that I could parse it later on Azure side. The effect is the same - I can see the input data, I can see the data after parsing - attributes and all values, but substitution of values from JSON for variables in App Logic does not work. Please take a look in the new screenshoots.

Comment: @Kivas, cause your json is in `application/json` however you could get the value with Dynamic menu so I recommend you test with enter the expression. And waht do you mean "ubstitution of values from JSON for variables in App Logic does not work. "? You mean you want to replace the json data with variable value? It's not allowed, you could only create json data with variable value.

Comment: I mean - I cannot initialize variable in flow with variables/properties from JSON. Please look into screenshoots - in Flow example I want to initialize variable test with 'timestamp' from JSON, but in next image you can check that this is null :(

Comment: @Kivas, would you mind send the json data, let me have a test, cause my variable could get the integer from json.